# How to record sound directly from output?

Tags: audio, connection, microphone, audio-recording

I'm not sure if I'm asking the question right, but I want to record sound, by connecting its output to my pc's mic input. Is this possible ?

I have a Line 6 POD 2.0 guitar processor, and a big jack to small jack adapter (see the image) , but I don't have any external audio card, so is there a way to record sound from it, without an external microphone, which causes noise ?

Will this work ?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You get what we call a line-in input. It is much less sensitive that the mic-in port and every motherboard should have one (the port colour is blue) by default. You can go to sounds options > recording devices to enable this port. Then go to your recording application (like Audacity) and select the line-in for recording.

Comment: Thanks, Rudolph ! But my pc does not have a line in input. It has only two sound sockets, mic and speakers..

Comment: Have you tried turning the mic input recording level to the minimum? Sounds like that would be your best option at this point, since only buying an external sound adapter might solve the problem completely.

Comment: @CengizFrostclaw Sometimes, the drivers (or audio software) on the computer (comes from the OEM or motherboard manufacturer) let you reconfigure a mic port as a line-in port.

Comment: Laptop sound cards aren't great for audio quality either, so you may want to look into buying an external sound card anyway.