# How to get sound from a 'record out' sound output into a Thinkpad

Tags: windows-7, audio, microphone, audio-recording, headphone-jack

The Lenovo Thinkpad T440 ([specifications](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/pd100280)) running Windows 7, and has all the latest audio drivers installed and reported to be working.  The machine has what's called a "Combo audio/microphone jack".  Typically a headset is plugged in there and you get stereo out and microphone input.  The connector has tip, ring 1, ring 2, and sleeve (TRRS) conductors.

The machine has no other audio input jacks except for the combo audio/mic jack that's got the headset symbol next to it:

[image: Ports on T400p]

The headset jack (apparently) takes a TRRS-CTIA style connector:

[image: TRRS connectors]

Using an adapter with TRRS (15mm in length, so the shorter one) on one end and three RCA connectors on the other, I have been able to get sound output from the Thinkpad laptop computer to some speakers (so that works fine).

[image: TRRS to RCA adapter]

I would expect that connecting the final connector from a separate device (that is producing an audio signal) from a "line out" or "record out" would 1) cause another "device" to appear in Windows (Realtek® HD Audio driver), and 2) audio signal to be available for applications to use.

The result, though, is that when I connect the 'line out' to the Thinkpad's microphone portion of the combo/audio microphone jack, there is no change in the driver (no additional mic is shown), and no sound from the external device is available.  This is true even if I request to display removed and deactivated devices.

Without anything plugged into the combo jack, when I go into "Recording Devices", I see a microphone as the default device. It's enabled, and showing audio (using the built-in mic).  When I plug in the TRRS adapter, the device remains enabled, but no longer shows audio (even though a signal is arriving). No additional device appears when plugging in the TRRS adapter.

This ['superuser' question](https://superuser.com/questions/640317/how-to-record-sound-directly-from-output) is similar, but not specific to Thinkpad and the answer is not applicable since there is no separate 'line in' available on the Thinkpad.

Is there some technique I can try in order to get the audio from an external line out to be available to applications in a Thinkpad running Windows 7?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have not installed the drivers correctly or the correct drivers. 
 Even when not plugged in I see on my T440/Win7-64 the microphone (built in) enabled and the mic-in-jack disabled. To check the driver open control panel -> sound -> tab record and look whats there.
 If there is nothing installed go to the Lenovo driver page (use the official divers because the Thinkpads are sometimes "immune" to 3rd party drivers. The [download (english) page is here](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-t-series-laptops/thinkpad-t440/downloads). 
If all drivers are installed and the status is not changeing in sound -> recording  
a) your mic-jack may be too short or 
b) the plug has a mechanical defect.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I had already been to the support page and the machine has all the most current drivers.  Your 'a) and b)' are a possibility, but because the sound output works through that connector (two of the three connections), I was thinking that the physical connection was working, and that the third of three connections was working.  My research indicates the mic signal is on the sleeve, so that might be it.  I don't see the spec for that combo jack on the Thinkpad site (whether it expects a 15mm or a 17.5mm).

Comment: Do you see the mic-jack as disabled in control panel-sound-recording? If no then its a driver issue, if yes its a/b I measured my triple-jack its around 17mm.

Comment: It may be possible that for your model of laptop the Headphone/Mic combo jack does not accept standalone conventional microphone input. It might be designed to work with an integrated Mic present in Headphones + Mic devices. Just a possibility. Do check with Lenovo support, just in case.

Comment: Without anything plugged into the combo jack, when I go into "Recording Devices", I see a microphone as the default device. It's enabled, and showing audio (using the built-in mic).  When I plug in the TRRS adapter, the device remains enabled, but no longer shows audio (even though a signal is arriving). No additional device appears when plugging in the TRRS adapter.

Comment: You should see TWO devices there - internal MIC enabled - green AND external MIC (= jack) disabled = red - So I guess its rather a driver or device configuration issue. In sound-recording´do a right click and activate show removed and deactivated devices

Comment: Thanks 007 for your assistance.  I don't show a second device, even if I show removed and deactivated, so your "a) or b)" is likely the problem.

Comment: No if its not there its a driver problem SOFTWARE not the hardware (which might later on be also a problem !)

Answer (score 0):

See if you can get your hands on one of the OEM sound adapters. They will convert a line/mic into the TRRS pin, but you won't be able to simultaneously use audio out. You can monitor the audio in through the built in laptop speakers. To avoid feedback the mic should be behind the speakers.

[image: Thinkpad sound adapters]